# Null is returned when sending data to server

Tags: java

**Client-Side Below**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TCPclient {
    
    
    
    public static void openChat() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean exit = false;
        while (!exit) {
            String input = keyboard.nextLine();
            if(input != null) {
                if ("quit".equals(input)) {
                    System.out.println("Exit programm");
                    exit = true;
                } else if ("/".equals(input)) {
                    //Do something
                    getInput();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void getInput() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        
        
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String message = scan.nextLine();
        
        sendMessage(message);
        
        openChat();
        
    }
    
    public static void sendMessage(String message) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        
        InputStream input = sock.getInputStream();
        OutputStream output = sock.getOutputStream();
        
        
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
        System.out.println(message);
        writer.write(message);
        
        
        sock.close();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        System.out.println("Type / to chat or quit to exit");
        
        openChat();
        
    }
    
}
```

**Server side Below**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class ServiceThread extends Thread {
    Socket sock;
    
    public ServiceThread(Socket sock) {
        this.sock = sock;
    }
    public void run() {
        
        
        try {
            InputStream input = sock.getInputStream();
            OutputStream output = sock.getOutputStream();
            
            byte request[] = new byte[100];
            input.read(request);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);
            String message = reader.readLine();
            
            System.out.println(message);
            
            sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
public class TCPserver {
    static ArrayList<ServiceThread> theClients = new ArrayList<ServiceThread>();
    public TCPserver() {
        
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ServerSocket serSock = new ServerSocket(9999);
        
        while(true) {
            Socket sock = serSock.accept();
            ServiceThread server = new ServiceThread(sock);
            theClients.add(server);
            server.start();
        }
    }

}
```

I get null returned when I want to get the client's message returned.
I am new to this so tell me if I am just doing this all wrong.
Also I would like to know how to you guys learned this information becuase I want to learn more about this and dont knoow where to learn it.

Comment: Which line is it? I learned from the web (not YouTube), from reading and doing exercises from many books, and programming for many years.

Comment: What do you think `input.read(request)` is doing?

Comment: It looks like, in the server, you read from the Stream, then created a BufferedReader, and read from that. So maybe there isn't anymore to read?

Comment: Your network communication concept is bad. Hard to amend without to rewrite the whole package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are server issues in your implementation.

1. Inside `ServiceThread`, the `run` method closes `sock(socket)`  that's why the connection closed after just staring.

Re-write `run` :

```
public void run() {
        
        try {
            DataInputStream inputStream = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
            //DataOutputStream output = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
            String  str=(String)inputStream.readUTF();  
            System.out.println("Client Echo:" + str);

            //sock.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2. Need to modify client implementation also:

- You initialize socket connection inside `sendMessage` method. So, you failed to communicate with the server. So, initialize `socket` in the constructor.

Modified `TCPclient`:

```
public class TCPclient {
    
    DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
    
    public TCPclient() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket sock = new Socket("localhost", 9999);
        dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    }

    public  void sendMessage(String message) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        System.out.println(message);
        dataOutputStream.writeUTF(message);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        
        TCPclient tcPclient = new TCPclient();
        System.out.println("Type / to chat or quit to exit");
        tcPclient.sendMessage("Hello From Client");
        tcPclient.openChat();
        
    }
}
```

It works for me. Try it. I use `DataInputpStream` and `DataOutputStrem` instead of `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, these are not major issue.

Comment: the concept is wrong and your modification makes the concept becoming a zombie. The client opened a socket and left it "unclosed". The same with ServiceThread. And that is bad. Very bad.

Comment: This is not like that, I have just wanted to focus on actual problem. Shout close socket based on any condition. Like if str.equals("/") return true then call socket.close()...